# How does active_support/inflector get included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I required `active_support/inflector` and now I'm able to use the `pluralize` method on strings.

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

module Foodie
  class Food
    def self.pluralize(word)
      word.pluralize
    end
  end
end

p Foodie::Food.pluralize("foo") #=> foos
```

But I was expecting to have to include the `ActiveSupport::Inflector` module as a mixin for it to work.

Why don't I need something like:

```
module Foodie
  class Food
    include ActiveSupport::Inflector
    def self.pluralize(word)
      word.pluralize
    end
  end
end

p Foodie::Food.pluralize("foo") #=> foos
```

Also the above example still works.

I thought the whole point of requiring a file is just so you have access to the classes/modules/methods/variables inside that file, but it doesn't necessarily include that functionality in all the modules and classes.

Maybe, is it because the ruby file with the Inflector module is opening up the string class? Like in this example:

foo.rb:

```
module Foo
end

class String
  def cats  
    self + " cats"
  end
end
```

bar.rb:

```
require_relative 'foo'

p "foobar".cats #=> "foobar cats"
```

Would love some guidance :)

Comment: You need one or more additional tags to indicate this is a Rails or Active Support question (and not a pure Ruby question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, String is getting monkeypatched here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb#L9

This is then included by the module you're requiring here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb#L7